# internet access but cannot open a page

Tags: windows-8

I have unlimited data from 12 am to 5 am. During this time internet connection is lost for about every 20 mins, and I think this automatically done by my ISP.

My main problem is after exhausting the unlimited time , that is from 5 am, you are connected and still have internet access but you cannot open a page or download. when you try opening a page it says,' page not found'.

Can any one help me with any method to continue browsing ?

Answer (score -1):

Try browsing through this website:

http://anonymouse.org/

What it does is it runs your ip through a proxy server and only then to the desired website. That way, it isn't actually your computer that's browsing the internet. Might help you get around your ISP's restrictions, but admittedly, it's a long shot.

Comment: Good. I just tried that but webpage reports "unable to connect to the internet. I have no credit or internet bundle yet still am connected to the internet. When I put my mouse pointer on the network icon on the taskbar it says" internet access".